# Using Mir display server with elementary

Tags: display

When and how will I be able to run elementary on Mir/Wayland display server? Is it going to be possible on the first release of Unity 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElementaryOS is in migration (or anything like this) to Wayland and is a long process to begin the default session but you can test it with `gala --wayland` in terminal, about Mir and the unity 8 release this don't support another Sessions for now only the Unity and the ubuntu touch

I hope this answer your question;

Sorry my Bad English XD